# How to plot exponential function using random data from numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot exponential distribution by generating random data from numpy random functions.

I am using `numpy.random.randint()` to generate the data for plot. But the plotted result is not as expected.

This is what I am doing-

```
x1= np.random.randint(15, size=15)
y1 = np.exp(x1)
plt.plot(x1,y1)
```

graph is plotted like below-

[image]

But when I plot the data generated with numpy.arange() plot seems to be correct. Here is the example below-

```
x = np.arange(0,15,1)
y = np.exp(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image: plot with range function]

I know that np.exp() have generated the correct y value. How is random data making difference?

Comment: this is becase the x values are randomized and *not* sorted so they move left to right relative to the order they come in. Sort them first

Comment: An alternative is to plot dots using '.' arg if you don't necessarily want a line trace..

Comment: The duplicate is perhaps not an *exact* duplicate, but the essence is the same: `plot` connects the points in the order given.  To see the curve that you expect, sort `x1` before computing `y1`.